# Eclipse - Keystore was tampered, or password is incorect. But yesterday it worked

Tags: android, keystore

I am using Eclipse export for signing apk file (right click on the project, than Export...). Eclipse ask me for keystore and password. I am sure i put the same password and the same keystore like before, but it does not work: Eclipse is writing Keystore was tampered, or password is incorect.

I do not why i could sign my .apk before and now it does not work. Without signing my .apk with the same keystore it is impossible to upload upgrade to market :-(.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If it says `Keystore was tampered, or password is incorect`, high chance that a wrong password was entered. Make sure you check for any caps in the password.

Secondly, make sure you use the same keystore for the same application you uploaded on the market.

One solution for you is if you still can't solve the problem, you will have to create another keystore and change the package name of your project.

Comment: Password is correct, i tried to change it by: keytool -storepasswd -keystore keystore1.jks